Translation for "acceptance is your best friend"
Would the phrase "acceptance is (your) best friend" be correctly translated to Latin as `
"Acceptatio optimus amicus est" 

or
"Acceptatio tua optima amica est"? 

Edit:
The word acceptance would be in the sense of "acceptance of (the) situation as it is", that one should accept the hand you're dealt and to continue with the work considering the circumstances.

It might be helpful if you provided more context, particularly about your intended meaning for acceptance. The English is quite idiomatic, so a literal translation is unlikely to have the intended meaning.

I'm not sure what you mean by acceptance, but I doubt acceptatio means what you want.
